# Finding next number in the sequence problem

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

*5, 10, 6.5, 8.5, 8, 7, 9, 5.5, 5,*

What is the next number in the sequence?

Comment: Hi radon and welcome to Puzzling :) I see you [cross-posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3740644/a-hard-next-number-in-the-sequence-problem) this on Math.SE. There you say it was an interview question you didn't know the answer to - is this still the case: do you still not know the answer and are you hoping somebody here might be able to help you answer it?

Comment: Hi @Stiv, thank you for the warm welcome :) I did not know the answer but now [hexomino](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/99624/43996) has answered it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm wondering if there might be a typo in the sequence and it should read something like this

> 5, 10, 6.5, 8.5, 8, 7, **9.5, 5.5**
>  This would involve swapping the last two commas for periods and the last period for a comma.
>  The reason I suggest this is that now the sequence follows a nice pattern
>  5 + 10 - 6.5 = 8.5
>  10 + 6.5 - 8.5 = 8
>  6.5 + 8.5 - 8 = 7
>  8.5 + 8 - 7 = **9.5**
>  8 + 7 - **9.5** = **5.5**
>  7 + **9.5** - **5.5** = 11
>  So the next term in the sequence would be **11**

The other idea I had was that

> We ignore elements of the sequence in the odd positions to get
>  _, 10, _, 8.5, _, 7, _, 5.5, _
>  Then we see that the elements in even positions follow an arithmetic sequence and the next element should be **4**.
>  I don't prefer this one though because it involves dropping half of the elements.

Comment: I spotted that exact same half-pattern (your second idea). It would be disappointing if it turned out to be correct with half the information unused, but it could very easily be a case of a mis-remembering by the OP or just a poorly concocted interview question...

Comment: @Stiv yes, the second one does not seem likely. I thought the typo theory might be legitimate as an interview candidate generally only has a small amount of time to answer a question and introducing a sequence with no reasonably deducible structure seems very unfair.

Comment: I thought the same, hadn't noticed the additive relationship, but you can express the same sequence as two sequences where the first is incrementing by +1.5 and the second by -1.5.

Comment: @hexomino - Yes, typo theory is legitimate, my bad. Sincere thanks for answering. Your other idea also seems reasonable but is not the answer. I have accepted the answer for your first idea.

Comment: @MrSethward - Your answer is also accepted!